# DRF - Return custom values from serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a `status` Character model field which can store either ("Y", "N", "I").

I have written `ModelSerializer` as below.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('status')
```

Now I want to return `Yes` or `No` or `Intermediate` for `status` instead of `Y` or `N` or `I`

How do you do that? What should I look for in document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override `to_representation()` method of a serializer and call `get_field_display()`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('status', )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['status'] = instance.get_status_display()
        return representation
```

Comment: The thing is, my models were created using inpectdb, so they don't have choices in models.py

Comment: @KishorPawar so the naive solution is: you could check a condition in `to_representation()` and show whenever you want, like `status=''  if instance.status == 'I': status='Intermediate'  elif status=='Y': status = 'Yes' ... representation['status'] = status`. But much better write this condition in a model method and call it in serializer once

Comment: Yes, that is what I though of doing, but I wanted to see if there is more clean way. Though I am trying by adding choices to model field.

Comment: @KishorPawar there is another question about `inspectdb` I never used it, sorry. You better ask a new question about this specific problem

Comment: my `to_representation` is not getting called.

Comment: @KishorPawar in which scenario? It'll called every time when you transfrom object to primitive data types, when you call `serializer.data`.

Comment: You were right, It was getting called, but there was a case mismatch in my choices tuple the value to be stored in db and actual value in db